Fulton-Harris Proposition C.17 clarification
There's a line in the proof of this proposition C.17 in Fulton-Harris that I don't understand. For completeness,the statement of the proposition is: Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V).$ Then for any element $X\in \mathfrak{g},$ the semisimple part $X_s$ and the nilpotent part $X_n$ are also in $\mathfrak{g}.$ The line I'm having trouble with says: Since $[X,\mathfrak{g}]\subset \mathfrak{g}$, it follows that $[p(X),\mathfrak{g}]\subset \mathfrak{g}$ for any polynomial $p(T)$. I do not think there any any additional assumptions at play here.
In particular it should hold that $[X^2,\mathfrak{g}]\subset \mathfrak{g}$, but even this is not clear to me.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}$
$\newcommand{g}{\mathfrak{g}}$
That line is fuzzy to me too, but since the purpose of that part is to show $\ad(X_s)(\g)\subseteq\g$ and $\ad(X_n)(\g)\subseteq\g$ we can instead argue

if $\ad(X)(\g)\subseteq \g$ then $p(\ad(X))(\g)\subseteq \g$ for any polynomial $p$;
the components $\ad(X)_s$ and $\ad(X)_n$ of the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition of $\ad(X)$ are polynomials in $\ad(X)$ so that $\ad(X)_s(\g)\subseteq \g$ and $\ad(X)_n(\g)\subseteq\g$; finally,
by exercise C.1 or otherwise one has $\ad(X)_s=\ad(X_s)$ and $\ad(X)_n=\ad(X_n)$, whence $\ad(X_s)(\g)\subseteq\g$ and $\ad(X_n)(\g)\subseteq\g$.

